# R reading data as factor values

Tags: mysql, r

I imported a .csv file into R but some of the columns seem to be being read as factors (I think that is the correct terminology).

A little background: I created the file in MySQL and exported it from there. The columns that are being read as factors are the ones that are NOT integer type columns in MySQL. (Varchar and decimals are being read as factors.)

For the varchar and decimal columns:

```
> data$column_a[1]
[1] 0.1186
1143 Levels: 0.0000 0.0112 0.0127 0.0135 0.0139 0.0141 0.0145 0.0149 0.0152 ... NULL
```

For integer columns:

```
> data$column_b[1]
[1] 177
```

I've never experienced this before, and I really have no idea what's going on. How do I change this so that they're read normally and column_a will appear like column_b does?

Comment: It's likely that `NULL` factor level that's the culprit.  Try reading again with `na.strings = "NULL"` in the `read.table()` call.  This will replace `NULL` with the appropriately classed `NA` variable and hopefully will fix the issue

Comment: What are the results of `badVals <- which(is.na(as.numeric(as.character(data$column_a)))); data$column_a[badVals]` ?

Comment: @RichardScriven so, that sort of solved it. The numeric columns did have some NULL values, and getting rid of them fixed that problem. But the strings still are the same (there weren't any nulls there)

Comment: For that I think you may just want `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @japem - I added my comments as an answer